# Send a javascript variable to the database using ajax or json

Tags: php, ajax, database

Hi i need help to a project, i develop a javascript intranet and am trying to send the score to the user's entity. I tried various ways but none works.

So i created two files, one is the application and the other is the ajax file that trying to send the variable to database.
I think but am not sure that the problem is in the ajax file that does not called when the application requests it.
Below is the code of file related to the ajax request, now what code i should alter to the extra file?

```
var score=count;
```

$.ajax(
{

```
type:"POST",
url:"localhost/xampp/htdocs/ajax.php",
dataType:"json",
data:score });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this type of practice here.

JS Code :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#submit").click(function(){
var somefiled = $("#somefield").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'somefield='+ somefield;
if(somefield=='')
{
    alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
    //AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            location.reload();
            }
    });
}
return false;
});
});
```

This would work when you click a button named `submit`. After clicking submit, it will find values for example `somefield`.

Now, in file.php, you can receive the variable as :-

```
$_POST['somefield'];
```